# optimization of constrained problems with three variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, equation

I have this equation

```
f(X) = (x3+2).x1.x2^x2
```

subject to

```
g(x) = 1-(x2.x2.x3)/71785.x1^4 <= 0
```

where `0.05 <= x1 <= 2`,`0.25<=1.3`, and `2<=x3<=15`

How to solve this for three variables with different interval of values ?

Comment: I count four variables: `x1 ... x4`. Furthermore I don't understand `(x3=2)x1` in `f(X)`.

Comment: http://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html

Comment: Thanks for help.But I have three different boundaries for x values as    where 0.05 <= x1 <= 2,0.25<=1.3, and 2<=x3<=15 which i require to use to evaluate F(X) values.At the end of algorithm i want to write x values ,F(X),G(X) in excel file.